# How do I ask for a job as web developer in USA

Tags: software-industry, hiring-process, internship, websites

I am a student and I moved to a town in USA to work during the summer.

I already have a job in a restaurant (in order to get the working visa) here, but since I am a computer science student with 1 year experience as a web developer I'd like to find a job/internship as a web developer.

I found two companies near me that do web development, but how do I ask them for a job (when they are not hiring).

For example when looking for a restaurant job (in USA) it's completely acceptable to go inside and ask the manager if they need someone/are hiring.

Can I do the same for more technical jobs. Can I just walk inside and talk to someone or should I send them an email (I don't like this idea because they might not completely understand me and I don't have much time). Is there any other option?

Comment: What visa are you on? Does it allow you to switch employers? Is it really only for the summer? If so, you might need to look for an internship.

Comment: Yes, it's only for the summer

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to go.  Call the company's main line.  Ask for their HR department.  Ask them if they are hiring or if you can at least fill out an application.

The second path is to call the company's main line and ask for their development or programming manager.  Then ask that person if they might be interested in hiring you.

Do a bit of research on each company so that you know what it is they do.  You might only get a few minutes with the dev manager so focus on what value you can bring to them.

Answer (score 0):

These companies will have a website check out their careers page to see if there is any opening. In this era of social media these companies might have an LinkedIn profile page check out job section and see if they are hiring